# Eclipse display all items from SQLite DB

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm new in Android programming and I'm stucked with retreiving data from SQLite DB and displaying it in my app in TextView / ListView. I've tried on many ways, but I'm just running in circles.. Any directions are welcome! Thanks.

Main.java:

```
public void LoadIngredient1() { 
    TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);         
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();       
    mDbHelper.open(); 

    // TO DO ?      

    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

TestAdapter.java:

```
public Cursor getData() {      
  String sql ="SELECT ID_Ingredient1, Ingredient1, tmp FROM Ingredient_1"; 
  Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null); 
  if (mCur!=null) 
  { 
    mCur.moveToNext(); 
  } 
 return mCur; 
}
```

Comment: look at this `www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial`

Comment: mCur.moveToFirst() is what you have missed. That would resolve your issue. Try doing that.

Comment: @MehulJoisar The thing is if I follow this tutorial: [link]www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial
I can't display items.
for (Contact cn : contacts) { 
String log="Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber(); 
// Writing Contacts to log 
Log.d("Name: ", log); 
For statement is never used. I created SQLite database, copy it to assets folder and on device.
boolean checkDataBase()
 {
     File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME); 
     Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists()); 
     return dbFile.exists(); 
 }
returns true.

Comment: @Moonbeam: I've download that demo project and confirmed that its working fine.if it doesn't working in your code then mention the errors which you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. I found this tutorial: http://mobisys.in/blog/tag/shipping-of-external-database-to-application/ Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to get a cursor? I would just build an object to return.Here is some sample code:
TestAdapter.java

```
    public class TestAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public TestAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        ...
        public YourObject getData() {
            YourObject yourObject = new YourObject();
            String sql ="SELECT ID_Ingredient1, Ingredient1, tmp FROM Ingredient_1"; 
            SQLiteDatabase mDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null); 
            if (mCur.moveToFirst()) { 
                yourObject.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID_Ingredient1)));
                yourObject.setIngridient(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID_Ingredient1)));
                ...
            } 
            return yourObject; 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ArrayList<MyDataObject> getData(){
    ArrayList<MyDataObject> result = new ArrayList<MyDataObject>();
    open database
    Cursor c = null;
    try{
   c = database.rawQuery("Select * from myDataObjectTable",null);
    while(c!=null && c.moveToNext()){
      MyDataObject object = new MyDataObject();

    object.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID Column")));
    object.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name")));
    object.setSomething(c.getBoolean(c.getColumnIndex("SOMETHING THERE COLUMN")));

    result.add(object);

    }

}catch(Exception e){
 Log.d(TAG,"some error",e);
} finally{

if(c!=null) c.close();
}
    return result;

    }
```